# Retrieve solver references

Tags: vba, excel

I have many files of my students who did some optimization (linear programming tasks via solver) in excel files (they did one optimization task per excel sheet).

Instead of reviewing them manually I want to get the parameters that they have given to solver via VBA (mainly: the references of target cell and variable cells, constraint references, method: Simplex LP, non-negativity check-box state).

I have researched it, but everywhere they try to explain how to **set** solver via VBA, not **get** which is what I need. So I need the functions that will give me these references for already set and optimized solver.

Comment: I have no personal experience with this but have you tried the [SolverGet](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/ff197007.aspx) function?